# usb flash drive is not mounting: "no such file or directory"

Tags: partitioning, mount, data-recovery, usb-drive

My flash drive is initially recognized on Ubuntu. However, it does not mount and, after a while, Ubuntu tells me that there was an error because it could not find the directory of the flash drive ("no such file or directory"); consequently, the flash drive does not appear as connected anymore. I've searching around trying fdisk, testdisk, etc., but, since the flash drive is not recognized, they did nothing.

I've ~1500 files with 66 kB (total of ~100 MB, in case this information matters) that I'd like to recover. I don't care if the flash drive cannot be recovered, my main concern is the files. What could I do?

The flash drive becomes hotter than usual after plugged in. May be a hardware problem?

Comment: Does it show up in the Gnome disk utility?

Comment: It shows up for a while and then disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to check whether the flash drive is recognized or not. We do that by using the `lsblk` command, on terminal.

Example:

```
ritesh ~> lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 107.4G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0   3.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdc      8:32   1   3.7G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1   3.7G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Here, `/dev/sdc1` is the device file for my USB drive. If you cannot find your flash drive, then there might be a hardware problem. 
If you find the device file, *proceed.*

Now, you can try to mount through terminal, using the `mount` command.
The syntax is:

```
sudo mount [device file] [location where you want to mount]
```

Example:

```
ritesh ~> sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media
[sudo] password for ritesh: 
ritesh ~> lsblk
```

If you cannot mount the flash drive and you do not care about the file names, you can use **PhotoRec** from **TestDisk** to recover your data. *(it works!)*

- Download TestDisk from [www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download)
- Now, once you have downloaded the `testdisk-7.0.linux26-x86_64.tar.bz2` file, extract it, either using Archive Manager or using the `tar` command.
- Once you have extracted it, in the `testdisk` directory, you will find the `photorec_static` file: execute it using `sudo`.

Example:

```
ritesh ~> cd Downloads/
ritesh Downloads> tar -xf testdisk-7.0.linux26-x86_64.tar.bz2 
ritesh Downloads> cd testdisk-7.0/
ritesh testdisk-7.0> ls
Android.mk  documentation.html  INFO  photorec.8       README           THANKS
AUTHORS     fidentify.8         jni   photorec.ses     readme.txt       VERSION
ChangeLog   fidentify_static    l     photorec_static  testdisk.8
COPYING     icons               NEWS  qphotorec.8      testdisk_static
ritesh testdisk-7.0> sudo ./photorec_static
```

Now, as the `photorec_static` file executes you just have to follow some simple steps to recover the files on your flash drives.

Photorec runs in the terminal and it looks like this:

```
PhotoRec 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

  PhotoRec is free software, and
comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.

Select a media (use Arrow keys, then press Enter):
>Disk /dev/sda - 120 GB / 111 GiB (RO) - KINGSTON SUV300S37A120G
 Disk /dev/sdc - 3918 MB / 3736 MiB (RO) - Kingston DT 100 G2








>[Proceed ]  [  Quit  ]

Note:
Disk capacity must be correctly detected for a successful recovery.
If a disk listed above has incorrect size, check HD jumper settings, BIOS
detection, and install the latest OS patches and disk drivers.
```

I have successfully recovered 320 GB of files from my external hard disk using `photorec`.

Comment: By the way, Photorec is only a carver and this limitation should clearly be written in the answer. Moreover, it can be installed easily using `apt-get`.

Comment: Thanks! It was recognized for a while and then I tried to mount. During the mounting, it disappeared. It seems to me that it is a hardware problem.